# Reading pixels into array for struct crashes program

Tags: c, struct

So basically I have a struct Pixel:

```
struct Pixel {
    int r;
    int g;
    int b;
} Pixel;
```

To store RGB values from a file like this:

```
0
240
233
2
234
42
```

Where each 3 values is the red, green and blue value respectively.

Now i've created an array of fixed width and height (I already know the image width and height), so here is the code I have so far:

```
#define WIDTH 640
#define HEIGHT 480

//new array of WIDTH rows, HEIGHT columns
struct Pixel *rgbArray[WIDTH][HEIGHT];
int x, y;
for(y = 0; y < HEIGHT; y++) {
    for(x = 0; x < WIDTH; x++) {
        struct Pixel *newPixel;
        fscanf(fd, "%d\n%d\n%d\n", &newPixel->r, &newPixel->g, &newPixel->b);
        rgbArray[x][y] = newPixel;
    }
}
```

It crashes without error, can anyone help me figure out why? I hope it's not something simply stupid ;_;.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `It crashes without error`... somehow I don't believe that. :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh there's no error in my CodeBlocks console

Comment: More usually `struct Pixel rgbArray[HEIGHT][WIDTH];` (transposed x<->y) and losing the `*` as advised by @iharob, and `rgbArray[y][x] = newPixel;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First problem

```
struct Pixel *newPixel;
```

is uninitialized and dereferencing it with the inderiction operator `->` is *undefined behavior* which might explain your crash, you don't seem to need a pointer so

```
struct Pixel newPixel;
```

should be fine, and then

```
if (fscanf(fd, "%d%d%d", &newPixel.r, &newPixel.g, &newPixel.b) == 3)
    rgbArray[x][y] = newPixel;
else
    handle_error();
```

provided that

```
struct Pixel rgbArray[WIDTH][HEIGHT];
```

Comment: Perfect, that solves the issue :) I think I should have another read over pointers and indirection operators